# how can the following data be organized into arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have these following values from a db using `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

```
Id - Val
0 - TextA
0 - TextB
1 - TextC
2 - TextD
2 - TextE
3 - TextF
```

I need to add these values into an array in php which can club values like this

```
0 - TextA,TextB
1 - TextC
2 - TextD,TextE
3 - TextF
```

Comment: Can't you do this at the db query? I had a similar requirement when using MySQL so I used group_concat - very handy.

Comment: I assume you are getting the data as an array?

Comment: @user519575: that's a good suggestion. I'd recommend posting it as an answer :)

Comment: @MeLight: the input format is unclear :/ I'm guessing he isn't getting the data as anything right now, and is just deciding what to put inside the loop where he's running `mysql_fetch_array`.

Comment: I am getting the data using mysql_fetch_assoc()

Comment: I read this incorrectly as wanting **string** array values (`TextA,TextB`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$organized = array();

foreach($rows as $r)
{
  if (!isset($organized[$r['Id']]))
  {
    $organized[$r['Id']] = array();
  }
  $organized[$r['Id']][] = $r['Val'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep it in something like this.

```
array(
   0 => array( 'TextA', 'TextB' ),
   1 => array( 'TextC' ),
   2 => array( 'TextD', 'TextE'),
   3 => array( 'TextF')
);
```

You can fill it with:

```
$array = array();
foreach ( $data as $item )
{
   $id = $item['id'];
   if ( !array_key_exists( $id , $array))
   {
      $array[$id] = array();
   }
   $array[ $id ][] = $item['value'];
}
```